# UIView Controller Instantiation

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to programatically instantiate a UIView and UIViewController but am having issues getting any of my labels,textfields etc being displayed.

My view controller looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class AdminNewsController: UIViewController {

var adminNewsView : AdminNewsView!


let newsTitleMarker : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Title: "
    label.font.withSize(AMA_Constants.FontSizes.HeadingSize)
    label.textColor = AMA_Constants.FontColor.LabelMarkingColor
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let newsTitleTextEdit : UITextField = {
    let textEdit = UITextField()
    textEdit.text = "Text View"
    textEdit.textColor = AMA_Constants.FontColor.LabelMarkingColor
    textEdit.textAlignment = .center
    textEdit.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return textEdit
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    adminNewsView = AdminNewsView()
    adminNewsView.backgroundColor = AMA_Constants.AppPrimaryColor
    self.view.addSubview(adminNewsView)

    setupViews()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = AMA_Constants.AppSecondaryColor
    self.navigationItem.title = "Admin - News"

}


func setupViews() {

    adminNewsView.addSubview(newsTitleMarker)
    adminNewsView.addSubview(newsTitleTextEdit)


    adminNewsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    adminNewsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    adminNewsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    adminNewsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    adminNewsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    newsTitleMarker.anchor(adminNewsView.topAnchor, left: adminNewsView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: AMA_Constants.Alignment_Space.paddingVerticalExternal, leftConstant: AMA_Constants.Alignment_Space.paddingHorizontalExternal, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)



    newsTitleTextEdit.anchor(newsTitleMarker.topAnchor, left: newsTitleMarker.rightAnchor, bottom: nil, right: adminNewsView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: AMA_Constants.Alignment_Space.paddingHorizontalInternal, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: AMA_Constants.Alignment_Space.paddingHorizontalExternal, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

}}
```

but in the simulator the view is the correct (white) colour but with no label or UITextView.

Questions:

1. Have I correctly instantiated and created the view adminNewsView?
2. Why is it not producing the label and UITextView?
3. Not thoroughly understanding MVC on IOS, what should be written in my adminNewsView class? I thought I should have my setupViews() function in it but it seems that's not the case.

Comment: Xcode has a view debugging feature that lets you see the views in the hierarchy, along with their sizes and placement at run time.

Comment: check AMA_Constants.FontColor.LabelMarkingColor returning correct color value, if it returns white, then you can't see the label. (while debugging use UIColor directory instead of using helper methods)

Comment: The colours are dark grey but I did check to make sure. Thanks phillip mills, I did not know about this feature. Checking it initially showed there was a constraint issue but have removed that without anything changing in the simulator.

Comment: I’m now starting to think that the UIView class iv instantiated (the class file is empty beyond the definition of the class) is wrong. What needs to be in there? Presumably something should happen when it is initialised through the initial instantiation when I write adminNewsView = AdminNewsView() ?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going on with your code that I had issues with so I refactored it in a way that I think will help illustrate the process of programmatic view controllers better for you. One of those issues was that you never created the view controller's view, which is mandatory for programmatic-view controllers.

I would highly recommend writing code like a book–left-to-right, top-to-bottom. Declare all of the properties that need to be instance properties first, call all of the lifecycle events next (I don't put any code in a lifecycle method that isn't a method call because it reads so much easier), and then write those methods out.

```
import UIKit

class AdminNewsController: UIViewController {


    // MARK: Properties


    let adminNewsView = AdminNewsView()
    let newsTitleMarker = UILabel()
    let newsTitleTextEdit = UITextField()


    // MARK: Lifecycle


    override func loadView() {

        // do NOT call super.loadView() when programmatically creating a
        // view controller

        // do all of your basic setup here in loadView

        setView()
        addAdminNewsView()
        addNewsTitleMarker()
        addNewsTitleTextEdit()

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // do call super.viewDidLoad() however
        // do post-basic setup stuff here in viewDidLoad
        // viewDidLoad is called after the entire view controller has been
        // loaded into memory so consider that

    }


    // other lifecycle events that come after viewDidLoad where you can do some
    // last-second touches include viewDidLayoutSubviews(), viewDidAppear(), etc.


    deinit {

        // do any cleanup here like deactivating timers, removing observers, etc.

    }


    // MARK: Methods


    func setView() {

        view = UIView()
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    }


    func addAdminNewsView() {

        adminNewsView.backgroundColor = AMA_Constants.AppPrimaryColor
        adminNewsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(adminNewsView)
        adminNewsView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        adminNewsView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        adminNewsView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        adminNewsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    }


    func addNewsTitleMarker() {

        newsTitleMarker.text = "Title: "
        newsTitleMarker.font.withSize(AMA_Constants.FontSizes.HeadingSize)
        newsTitleMarker.textColor = AMA_Constants.FontColor.LabelMarkingColor
        newsTitleMarker.textAlignment = .center
        newsTitleMarker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        adminNewsView.addSubview(newsTitleMarker)

        // add newsTitleMarker constraints

    }


    func addNewsTitleTextEdit() {

        newsTitleTextEdit.text = "Text View"
        newsTitleTextEdit.textColor = AMA_Constants.FontColor.LabelMarkingColor
        newsTitleTextEdit.textAlignment = .center
        newsTitleTextEdit.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        adminNewsView.addSubview(newsTitleTextEdit)

        // add newsTitleTextEdit constraints

    }


}
```

Since you asked, here is what a subclassed `UIView` may look like. Notice the different lifecycle methods.

```
class SomeView: UIView {


    // MARK: Properties


    private let itemBanner = UIImageView()
    private let itemLabel = UILabel()
    var itemName: String
    var itemPicture: UIImage


    // MARK: Lifecycle


    init(name: String, picture: UIImage) {

        self.itemName = name
        self.itemPicture = picture
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        config()
        addItemBanner()
        addItemLabel()

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()

        setConstraints()

    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // this can be a very useful method when subclassing views

    }


    // MARK: Methods


    private func config() {

        isOpaque = false

    }


    private func addItemBanner() {

        itemBanner.image = itemPicture
        itemBanner.clipsToBounds = true
        itemBanner.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        itemBanner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(itemBanner)

    }


    private func addItemLabel() {

        itemLabel.text = itemName
        itemLabel.textAlignment = .left
        itemLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        itemLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        itemLabel.font = UIFont.bigTitle
        itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        itemBanner.addSubview(itemLabel)

    }


    private func setConstraints() {

        // banner
        itemBanner.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        itemBanner.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        itemBanner.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        itemBanner.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 96).isActive = true
        itemBanner.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        // label
        itemLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemBanner.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        itemLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemBanner.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        itemLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemBanner.widthAnchor, constant: -32).isActive = true
        itemLabel.sizeToFit()

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this answer, it must have taken a while to do. My questions are now as to why you have removed the initialisation of my label and text edit to separate functions? What’s the point of that? I dont understand. For having an mvc pattern, how do I separate my view controller and the contents which should go in a view file???

Comment: You certainly don't have to, I just refactored it that way to better illustrate `UIViewController`. I am also OCD about my code and this is the style that I use, I think it reads the best and makes debugging easiest. You also asked about subclassing `UIView`, which is a different approach to subclassing `UIViewController`, so keep that in mind as well.

Comment: MVC is open to interpretation and not everyone implements it the same way. For what you're trying to do, the `M` is most likely going to be data from a data source (i.e. a database on a server) and the custom model objects you create in Swift to package them; `V` is going to be the label that interprets that data visually onto the screen; `C` is going to be the view controller that instantiates and positions that label.

Comment: Ok. So all my other views have a subclasses view and view controller which I’ve separated into different files (rightly or wrongly). I’m keen to understand what should go into my subclasses view file to help maintain the mvc pattern. This is what I’m struggling to comprehend. Any help understanding the physical code which could/should go in there would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: The number of files is practically irrelevant, what counts is the number of objects. This view controller that I refactored here is a single object and whether you keep it in the same file with other objects is meaningless to MVC. Views and view controllers both have lifecycles and once you understand them, it should all make sense to you. I would begin your research there.

Comment: I edited my answer to include what a subclassed `UIView` may look like.

Comment: Using the View Debugger I've noticed that my views are being covered up by the navigation bar. When i've referenced view.topAnchor previously it's taken this into account. Presumably there's an offset I need to include or am I adding the navigation bar afterwards which is causing it to overlap my label and textEdit?

Comment: `if #available(iOS 11.0, *) { someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true } else { someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true }`